# Как высчитать наносекунды из спарсенной даты? LocalDateTime

Tags: java, дата

Из строки забираю дату в формате:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

При попытке сравнить эту дату с `LocalDateTime.now()` я всегда получаю так, что текущая дата после даты из строки. Плюс дата из строки отдает 0 при `.getNano()`

Пример:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
String dateStr = "2012-01-20T02:15:12";
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, DATE_FORMAT);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А вас не смущает, что в строке наносекунд вовсе нет?

Comment: Смущает, конечно же. Как тогда сравнивать эти даты?

Comment: Ну если во входной строке наносекунд нету значит у вас им взять неоткуда, тут магии нет. Если вы хотите сравнить с текущим локальным временем, то установите ему наносекунды в 0 `LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0)`

Comment: @Alexandr спасибо, разобрался. Использовал 'DatatypeConverter.parseDatetime()'